# Is an Observer pattern useful in JS?

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I've read some articles about the Observer design pattern in JavaScript, but I don't get it: it seems to me quite useless since JS has events. Am I missing something?

Comment: the observer pattern is kind of on top of the event system.It allows to structure complex code more easily

Comment: The DOM Api of the browser or other libraries/apis provide events, but there are no events in the JavaScript specification. The libraries implement an event system by their own or use the one provided by the environment.

Comment: Isnt the DOM api actually an observer pattern? `someel.addEventListener("click",handler)` ?

Comment: Technically, events are one of possible implementations of the observer pattern. Other implementations are also possible (take RxJS or node's EventEmitter).

Comment: Observers via proxy are not events, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy code remains blocked and current execution stops untill the trap has executed then continues on. The execution context remain on the call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reacting to events like click, resize etc is one thing but limited to the DOM events. However without going into details here, if you look at a library like [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) (which uses the Observer pattern) you will be able to build powerful Reactive systems, where essentially anything could be treated like events, which in addition to the standard event system, they can be composed, mapped, etc

Comment: RxJS uses observables, not the "observer pattern".